# How to use hidden type and have a validation on radio buttons in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

```
 <input type="hidden" value="{{r.radioname}}" name="{{field.Name}}" 
                  ng-model="inputfield[field.Name][r.radioname]" required>
 <input type="radio"   id="radio_{{$index}}"  value="{{r.radioname}}" name="{{field.Name}}" 
                  ng-model="inputfield[field.Name][r.radioname]">
 <span style="width:115px;text-transform: capitalize">{{r.radioname}}</span>
```

I have tried like above but its not working.I want to have the submit button disable until the radio button is selected.When i directly give required to input `type="radio"` its not working.

So i have chosen another way by using hidden still its not working.Can any one please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

For validating radio button field add `ng-required` with negotiation of `ng-modal`.

**example** :

```
ng-model="inputfield[field.Name][r.radioname]" then
ng-required="!inputfield[field.Name][r.radioname]"
```

Comment: No even if i use it..its not working..For the first choosing option its the button is not getting enabled..But for again choosing other option the button is enabled..It means that when we choose the option 2 times but different option the button is enabling.for first choosing its not getting enabled

Comment: Could you please share your code again with more then two line? i want to understand what's actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

In `AngularJs` you could use `ng-hide` with value `true` or `false` directive on particular element to hide any control.

**example:**

```
<input ng-hide="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ng-disabled`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CEAQFjAGahUKEwjMlJX8qJTJAhWJ0hoKHcEwA2M&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.angularjs.org%2Fapi%2Fng%2Fdirective%2FngDisabled&usg=AFQjCNHOav3ZgQah8xrBjGIlHzBcWKt1jA&sig2=MrLN3GKbEVpNpROwtnF3OA&bvm=bv.107467506,d.d2s&cad=rja) to disabe the submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" />
```